# How to load JQuery easing script in wordpress?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, scripts

Ok, first of all, I know how to do this manually.
I could just download easing, place it in my plugin folder and load it using `wp_enqueue_script`. However, I want to load my script in a long-term way, ensuring that I use the same version of the easing script wordpress uses.

So what I am looking for, is a way to load easing in wordpress using `wp_enqueue_script`, as seen below. I have looked at the [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for `wp_enqueue_script`, but I can't seem to find the right file/handle to enqueue. Is there anyone who knows how to load the WordPress-native easing script?

```
//I know this works because I've used it a thousand times already
wp_enqueue_script("jquery");

//I want something like this without having to use my own script
wp_enqueue_script("jquery-easing");
```

Comment: If the file isn't listed there in the list of available files, then it isn't included with WordPress.

Comment: Wordpress has no easing script included. See [the list of scripts included in wp](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress) you will not foud easing. If you don't trust codex, you can look into the folder wp-includes/js and search jor easing script.

Comment: I had no idea the js files were in wp-includes folder. Learned something new today, thank you! If you post your answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you refer to [this](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) script, this is not included in wordpress.
See the codex for [list of scripts included in wp](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress) you will not find it.

If you don't trust codex, you can look into the folder `wp-includes/js` and search for easing script... it's not there.

### Edit (additional info)

Answer above just 'strictly' respond to the OP question, because the plugin he want to include actually is not a standard wordpress script.
However, as @Johannes Pille noticed in his answer, [jQuery UI Effects](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) that is a standard wordpress script that can be enqueued using `wp_enqueue_script("jquery-effects-core")`, **contains easing functions**.
This easing function was introduced by jquery team independently from the plugin mentioned by OP. In old version of jquery ui the easings available were less than now (I can't remember in which version all easing has been introduced) and to use some advanced easings it was necessary using the mentioned plugin.
When jquery team insert all now available easing, plugin developer update and **rename** his plugin easing functions to be compatible with jquery ui ones (all are implementation of [Rober Planner equations](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/)).
So, if someone has scripts that rely on the old-named plugin function **must** use the plugin, preferably the compatibility version).
If old names are not requested, standard wordpress `jquery-effects-core` can be used as well.

Please also notice that the plugin script minified is less than 4kb, jquery-effects-core minified is 12.76 kb, so if effect is not needed including the plugin is probably better.
On the other side, including the plugin **and** jquery ui effects does not make sense (unless, again, there are scripts that rely on old-named plugin easing function).

Answer (score 3):

I am not 100% certain, but as far as I know, the [easings](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) are part of [jQuery-UI Effects](http://api.jqueryui.com/category/effects-core/).

And hence *should* be loaded when enqueueing `jquery-effects-core`...

Comment: Yes, or 'sort of'. [The plugin OP refers](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) in previous version had different names for easing, that now (version 1.3) are changed to jquery ui effect standard easing names. But if you have script that rely on old easing names you need the plugin. Moreover, the plugin file minified is less than 4 Kb, effects core minified is 12.76 kb, so if you don't need effects... @Johannes Pille

Comment: It was not my intention to discredit your answer, @G.M. Simply added this for the sake of completeness. As you might have guessed from the fact that I mentioned not being certain, the further information you just provided was not known to me at all. Nevertheless, the statement "Wordpress has no easing script included" does not exactly hold true either. Also, the OP mentions wanting to "use the same version [...] WordPress uses". Proposal: Add both the existence of the option to use `jquery-effects-core` as well as your comment's contents into your answer - you'd have my upvote for sure.

Comment: Hi @Johannes Pille, I did **not** think you wanted to discredit my answer, I also reply to your comment for the sake of completeness. And following your suggestion I've edited my answer.

Comment: It seems that the easing is indeed in there. Thanks for your answer! ;)